# Tableau Desktop - How do you combine multiple Calculated Fields into one to use as a Filter?

Tags: tableau-api

[image][image]Allow me to preface this by saying if you know of a simpler way to achieve what I'm trying to accomplish I'm open to suggestions. I'm self taught on tableau desktop and I've only been working in this platform form for eight months.

I have seven calculated fields that are created to measure the severity of Gross and Net defects by count (Severe, Moderate, Minor and Pass). So for example for the Gross measure I have a calculated field written as follows:

```
CountD(IIF([Initial Loan Rating]="Minor",[Id (Projectloanfiles)],Null))
```

and the name of this calculated field is '-Gross Minor'

and the Net measure is:

```
CountD(IIF([Initial Loan Rating]="Minor",[Id (Projectloanfiles)],Null))
```

and the name of this calculated field is '-Net Minor'

to adjust for the other four levels, I'm simply changing "Minor" to, Moderate, Severe or Pass and adjust the name of the calculated field accordingly. Then I grab the calculated fields I've created, drag them to rows.

So these all work great, but I'd like to also create a filter using a calculated field to where it would toggle between showing "Gross" or "Net" defects. I know I could just create a separate worksheet, one showing only Gross and another showing only Net. But I'd rather try and keep the number of worksheets as low as possible.

All help is much appreciated!

Scott

Comment: The gross and net calculations are the same. Instead of 4 different calculated fields, why not drag Initial Loan Rating to columns, and have COUNTD([Id (Projectloanfiles)] on rows?  That doesn't solve the question you're asking per se, but it could be a set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly then you solve this using `Parameters`

Create a parameter with datatype `String` and then add custom values `Gross` and `Net`.

Now you can use only single sheet and change your formulas as below:

```
if [Parameter]="Gross"
CountD(IIF([Initial Loan Rating]="Minor",[Id (Projectloanfiles)],Null)) //'-Gross Minor'
elseif [Parameter]="Net"
then CountD(IIF([Initial Loan Rating]="Minor",[Id (Projectloanfiles)],Null)) //'-Net Minor'
end
```

By this process you will be having 4 formulas and using parameter you can toggle between the **Gross** and **Net**

EDIT----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
IF [Gross/Net Parameter]="Gross"  AND [Initial Loan Rating]="Minor"     //'-Gross Minor'
THEN [Id (Projectloanfiles)]
ELSEIF [Gross/Net Parameter]="Gross"  AND [Initial Loan Rating]="Moderate"   //'-Gross Moderate' 
THEN [Id (Projectloanfiles)]
ELSEIF [Gross/Net Parameter]="Gross"  AND [Initial Loan Rating]="Severe"    //'-Gross Severe' 
THEN [Id (Projectloanfiles)]
ELSEIF [Gross/Net Parameter]="Net"  AND [Final Loan Rating]="Pass"    //'-Net Pass
THEN [Id (Projectloanfiles)]
ELSEIF [Gross/Net Parameter]="Net"  AND [Final Loan Rating]="Minor"    //'-Net Minor'
THEN [Id (Projectloanfiles)]
ELSEIF [Gross/Net Parameter]="Net"  AND [Final Loan Rating]="Moderate"   //'-Net Moderate'
THEN [Id (Projectloanfiles)]
ELSEIF [Gross/Net Parameter]="Net"  AND [Final Loan Rating]="Severe"   //'-Net Severe'
THEN [Id (Projectloanfiles)]
ELSE Null
END
```

Comment: youre missing that there are 7 calculated fields Im trying to capture here. the calculation you supplied

if [Parameter]="Gross"
CountD(IIF([Initial Loan Rating]="Minor",[Id (Projectloanfiles)],Null)) //'-Gross Minor'
elseif [Parameter]="Net"
then CountD(IIF([Initial Loan Rating]="Minor",[Id (Projectloanfiles)],Null)) //'-Net Minor'
end


Its only capturing 2 aspects of what Im trying to filter through. I need this to field/filter to be able to toggle between ALL Gross & Net defaults.

I tried your direction but to no avail

extend with more ELSE or ELSEIF stmts to cover rest?

Comment: you want to merge all `Severe, Moderate, Minor and Pass` into one calculated field? along with Gross and Net?

Comment: Correct, the Gross and Net filter I'm trying to create is for Gross to capture all Minor, Moderate, Severe and the Net to capture all of the Pass, Minor, Moderate, Severe.

Comment: So the Gross items are coming from [Initial Loan Rating] with the levels of Minor, Moderate and Severe. The Net items are coming from [Final Loan Rating] with the levels of Pass, Minor, Moderate and Severe.

Comment: IF [Gross/Net Parameter]="Gross"
THEN(IIF([Initial Loan Rating]="Minor",[Id (Projectloanfiles)],Null)) //'-Gross Minor'
AND CountD(IIF([Initial Loan Rating]="Moderate",[Id (Projectloanfiles)],Null)) //'-Gross Moderate'
AND CountD(IIF([Initial Loan Rating]="Severe",[Id (Projectloanfiles)],Null)) //'-Gross Severe'

Comment: ELSEIF  [Gross/Net Parameter]="Net"
THEN(IIF([Final Loan Rating]="Pass",[Id (Projectloanfiles)],Null)) //'-Net Pass'
AND CountD(IIF([Final Loan Rating]="Minor",[Id (Projectloanfiles)],Null)) //'-Net Minor'
AND CountD(IIF([Final Loan Rating]="Moderate",[Id (Projectloanfiles)],Null)) //'-Net Moderate'
AND CountD(IIF([Final Loan Rating]="Severe",[Id (Projectloanfiles)],Null)) //'-Net Severe'
END

Comment: I've tried the above in one calculated field, but I'm having an issue with the 'AND' statement. It's saying that it can't logically AND integer and integer values.

Comment: @S.Francis that way doesn't work.. will post edit to that in 5 min

Comment: so the calculated field now shows that its valid, but its placing the calculated field as a Measure, and when i move it Filters its asking how i would like it to Filter via Sum, Average, Count, CountD, etc. I chose CountD then its asking me to set a Range of Values vs. just being able to choose Gross or Net. I close that, choose to view Parameter Control and when I toggle between Gross and Net nothing is happening. Sorry for all the questions, I've never had to build something like this.

Comment: post image of your sheet

Comment: i have added an image

Comment: This formula should be used as a measure in sheet but not as a filter... what is the purpose of using this formula in filter?

Comment: Im going this route is because having these 7 line graphs on one worksheet is noisy & people are getting lost in the data. Rather than creating 2 worksheets (one for Gross one for Net) Id like to have a filter built into the worksheets that will provide the ability to toggle between viewing Gross (Minor, Moderate, Severe) and Net (Pass, Minor, Moderate, Severe).

I have several other dashboards that reflect similar data (Gross and Net) so Im trying to keep the # of pages for this project at as few as possible. 

I cant express how grateful I am for you taking them time to help with this.

Comment: For these kind of design placing the formula in filter doesn't work because your data is populated with multiple aggregate functions in rows shelf, So for this to work you need to change the logic of Aggregate functions. If data is not confidential then share the workbook or you can implement the same logic in aggregate functions and check the result.

Comment: @S.Francis this forum is place to help and support, so no issues.. if my knowledge has helped to solve the problem, I will be happy

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the workbook due to confidentially. but your guidance is extremely helpful! I will move this issue to resolved and work down the path of adjusted the logic of the aggregate functions. Again thank you so very much for your time and attention.

Comment: @S.Francis No Problem.. if you think issue is resolved accept it as asnwered